# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in public function php not working

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

I am new to php and working on a pdo crud class. My insert function by itself works, but I am trying to have one function for both insert and update. I researched and saw that you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to do this, but when I add it to my function it does not work.

Here is my original INSERT that works;

```
//INSERT
public function insert($product_name,$color,$description,$used_for){
    $query="INSERT INTO makeup SET product_name='$product_name', color='$color', description='$description', used_for='$used_for'";
    $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."product cannot inserted");

    if($result){
        header('location:read.php');    
    }
}
```

and here is the one with the added ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (not working) no error messages, items simply do not update or insert

```
//INSERT and UPDATE
public function insert($product_name,$color,$description,$used_for){
    $query="INSERT INTO makeup SET product_name='$product_name', color='$color', description='$description', used_for='$used_for'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE makeup SET product_name='$product_name', color='$color', description='$description', used_for='$used_for'";
    $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."product cannot inserted");

    if($result){
        header('location:read.php');    
    }
}
```

and called by using:

```
include('Crud_class.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $obj=new Crud("localhost","root","password","dbname");
extract($_REQUEST);
$obj->insert($product_name,$color,$description,$used_for);
```

}

Comment: What doesn't work? Are there any error messages?

Comment: You also have a syntax error in the original one, so there is no way that could possibly work.

Comment: syntax error corrected happened in copying code here not in original code

Comment: items no longer insert nor update

Comment: its probably an sql error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error. There is no ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE *tablename SET* instead use

```
INSERT INTO makeup SET product_name='$product_name', color='$color', description='$description', used_for='$used_for'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_name='$product_name', color='$color', description='$description', used_for='$used_for'
```

Comment: the function now looks like this: public function insert($product_name,$color,$description,$used_for){
  $query="INSERT INTO makeup SET product_name='$product_name', color='$color', description='$description', used_for='$used_for'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_name='$product_name', color='$color', description='$description', used_for='$used_for'";
  $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."product cannot inserted");
 
  if($result){
   header('location:read.php'); 
  }
 }    But only the Insert portion of it is working :S